# Nested loops not getting desired output

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, nested

I'm trying to get this nested loop to work for a bigger program. This is just a small portion of my code

I want my program to match a file name in a folder to a file name in a text document, and if they match do something. I have no clue why the following nested loop is not working.

```
allGood = open("allGood.txt", "r")
folder = "C:\your\folder\path\here"

for item in allGood:
    for file in os.listdir(folder):

        if file == item:
            print "in item loop" + item
            print "Do a thing"
    print "1 loop completed"
```

The contents of "allGood.txt"

```
document10080.pdf
document10098.pdf
document10119.pdf
document10172.pdf
document10178.pdf
and so on
```

The problem is when it gets to the IF statement. It should match only once per loop, but it doesn't. I am only getting a huge output of "1 loop completed"

Output from inserting `print(file, item)`

```
('document10486.pdf', 'document10080.pdf\n')
('document10487.pdf', 'document10080.pdf\n')
('document10488.pdf', 'document10080.pdf\n')
('document10489.pdf', 'document10080.pdf\n')
('document1049.pdf', 'document10080.pdf\n')
```

**I see my problem now**

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune so do you want me to add a "folder" object? what else am I missing?

Comment: What is folder in your second for? It isn't defined anywhere

Comment: @SPYBUG96: As I said, the posting should be self-contained.  The input file is missing and the return of os.listdir won't match your needs.  Hard-code those lists, and you should be fine.

Comment: @FlorianGD just added it to the description, it is a path to a folder with files in it

Comment: @SPYBUG96 -- I noticed that, and edited my comment.

Comment: And are you sure that there is a file in your folder that is in your all good file?

Comment: @SPYBUG 96 did u try `for item in allGood.readlines()`

Comment: Before we go any further, you might show us the results of your basic debugging.  `print (file, item)` will show what you're actually comparing -- and should be part of your diagnosis already.

Comment: Remember, `allGood` is a file handle, *not* the file contents.

Comment: Please provide an example showing the contents of `allGood.txt` and the files in `C:\your\folder\path\here` and the expected and actual output. Also bear in mind that the backslashes in the path should be escaped: `"C:\\your\\folder\\path\\here"`

Comment: @Prune I think you just solved my problem, ugh, I'm such an idiot

Comment: @SPYBUG96  Welcome to the *homo sapiens* club, which I generally refer to as `H. Sap.`  Been there, done that, could make a football-field-sized flag from the T-shirts.

Comment: @Prune If you want to see what the problem is, I added the output of print(file, item)

Comment: @SPYBUG96: and there's your other problem: you have to `strip` the white space form the file name.  I included that in my answer (although Loren's is one I was about to post, so I'm glad you already accepted that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so i'll try an answer with insufficient informations. Basically you never have a match. That's why you never enter the second loop.

Did you consider handling the filenames as sets?:

```
real_files = set(os.listdir(folder))
good_files = set(open("allGood.txt", "r").readlines())

matching_files = good_files.intersection(real_files)
for file in matching_files:
    pass # do something
```

Also the text-file entries may contain white-spaces; consider using 'strip`, e.g:

```
import string
...
good_files = set(map(string.strip, open("allGood.txt", "r").readlines()))
...
```

or somewhat less "Perl-ish" ;-)

```
...
good_files_raw = open("allGood.txt", "r").readlines()
good_files = set(map(string.strip, good_files_raw))
...
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this tactic -- good work.  BTW, lack of reputation is *not* an excuse to post a comment as an answer.  This qualifies as an answer, however.

Comment: Yeah I've had a long day and I just completely forgot about that Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remember, allGood is a file handle, not the file contents.  Perhaps what you need is something like this:

```
folder = os.listdir("C:\your\folder\path\here")

with open("allGood.txt", "r") as allGood:
    for line in allGood:
        line = line.strip()
        if line in folder:
        ...
```